# Confirmation alert before exiting tvOS Apps will reject the app?

Tags: tvos

I know a lot of iOS apps already got reject by Apple Guidelines because of calling exit(0) or other ways of exiting apps.

But I'm unsure if something changed lately, because I couldn't find that in the current Apple docs.

My goal is to show an alert confirmation when pressing the Apple TV menu button. It will ask if the user wants to exit or stay in the app. Is it currently possible, or still a risk of the app being rejected?